# Getting Data From Sql Server 2008 with C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make a login facility for Windows Forms Application project. I'm using  Visual Studio 2010 and MS Sql Server 2008.

I referenced this article:
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Here is my database table named user:
[image]

I have `TextBox1` **for user name** , `TextBox2` **for user password** and `Button1` **for starting login process**. Here is my code for `Button1_Click` method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string kullaniciAdi; // user name
    string sifre; // password

    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
    myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; database=EKS; uid=sa; pwd=123; connection lifetime=20; connection timeout=25; packet size=1024;";
    myConn.Open();
    try 
    {
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        string myQuery = ("select u_password from user where u_name='" + textBox1.Text + "';");
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery,myConn);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            sifre = myReader["u_password"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
    }
    myConn.Close();
}
```

I don't have much experience with C# but i think i'm missing something small to do it right. Below i share exception message that i catched. Can you show me what i'm missing? (line 33 is `myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();`)

[image]

Considerin given answers, i updated my try block as in below but it still does not work.

```
try
{
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    string myQuery = ("select u_password from [user] where u_name=@user");
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConn);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        sifre = myReader["u_password"].ToString();
    }

    if (textBox2.Text.Equals(sifre))
    {
        Form2 admnPnl = new Form2();
        admnPnl.Show();
    }
}
```

After changing whole code as below by sine's suggestion, screenshot is also below:
And i think, somehow i cannot assign password in database to the string sifre.

code:

```
string sifre = "";
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "localhost";
builder.InitialCatalog = "EKS";
builder.UserID = "sa";
builder.Password = "123";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select u_password from [user] where u_name = @u_name";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u_name", textBox1.Text);
        conn.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var tmp = reader["u_password"];
                if (tmp != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    sifre = reader["u_password"].ToString();
                }
            }

            if (textBox2.Text.Equals(sifre))
            {
                try
                {
                    AdminPanel admnPnl = new AdminPanel();
                    admnPnl.Show();
                }
                catch (Exception y)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("incorrect password!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I attached it as image. It's in the end of my question

Comment: try changing `FROM user` to `FROM EKS.dbo.user`

Comment: you should use Parameters for Queries!!!

Comment: Not related to your problem at all but you need to be careful of somthing called [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Try typing this in your user login box: `'; drop database EKS; --`

Comment: @makciook it's still giving same error message

Comment: @sine hi, i'm afraid i didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım Look at Soner Gonul's answer, he changed your query to use parameters. If you don't do that people can run code on your SQL server (like deleting your database like my example did in my last comment). By using parameters like `@user` they can no longer do that.

Comment: @SonerGönül Sadly it's not solved. I changed my try block, it's at the end of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put user into [ ] because it is a reseved Keyword in T-SQL and use Parameters, your code is open to SQL-Injection!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "servername";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "databasename";
    builder.UserID = "username";
    builder.Password = "yourpassword";

    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select u_password from [user] where u_name = @u_name";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u_name", textBox1.Text);
            conn.Open();

            using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     var tmp = reader["u_password"];
                     if(tmp != DBNull.Value)
                     {
                         sifre = reader["u_password"].ToString();
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i revised my code based on your recommendation but it's not working. can you check latest state of my try block? it's in the end of my post. I cannot find what i'm missing

Comment: Are you still getting the same Exception or a differnt one?

Comment: though I do not know whats causing the Problem, I´ve updated my answer try this code and if it doesn´t work, update your question with the Exception(if it´s not the same as before)

Comment: var tmp = myReader["u_password"]; in the while loop gives this error:

Use of unassigned local variable 'myReader'

Comment: sorry for that, my bad forgot to change the name! It should be reader[..] updated my answer!

Comment: i think last change didn't make any difference. still gives the same error as previous. i updated question, you can check error message from there. btw, appreciated for help :)

Comment: blame on me...didn´t run the code and forgot to assign the connection to the SqlCommand updated my answer! Try it again ;-)

Comment: and if you´ve got it running maybe you should summarize you´re Question ;-)

Comment: updated my question with screenshot. i think, somehow i cannot assign password in database to the string sifre. i'm starting to get confused :s

Comment: check the chat ;)
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37476/discussion-between-sine-and-timur-aykut-yildirim

Comment: check the chat too ;)

Comment: i checked chat, check chat :D

Answer (score 4):

`User` is a *[reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* in T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[User]`.

And you should use [parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
string myQuery = "select u_password from [user] where u_name=@user";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery,myConn);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
```

As a general recomendation, *don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.*

Answer (score 1):

`User` is a reserved keyword in SQL, you need to do this:

```
select u_password from [user]  where u_name=@user
```

And as ever, with basic SQL questions, you should *always* use parameterised queries to prevent people from running any old commands on your DB via a textbox.

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery,myConn);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

USER is a reserved word in T-SQL

Try putting [] around reserved words.

```
string myQuery = ("select u_password from [user] where u_name='" + textBox1.Text + "';");
```

Answer (score 1):

[user is a keyword.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Change it to something like

```
string myQuery = ("select u_password from [user] where u_name='" + textBox1.Text + "';");
```

Futher to that I recomend you have a look at [Using Parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection Attacks in SQL Server](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)